# v-select display different item-text on clicking drop down

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The question is related to v-select and specifically on how I can show different value when a drop down is clicked. Below is my code and I've a drop down with country & code info. When a dropdown is selected, I would like the 'country' value to be displayed (eg., Austria (+43) but a value is selected, I'd like the 'code' value to be displayed (eg., +43 instead of Austria (+43)). How do I change this? I tried using 'onchange' event but couldn't figure out. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-content>
          <v-container fluid class="w-[680px]">
            <v-row no-gutters class="pt-[15px]">
              <v-col cols="2" sm="1" md="2" lg="1" xl="1"> </v-col>
              <v-col align-self="center" cols="2" sm="1" md="2" lg="1" xl="1">
                <v-select
                  class="text-blue"
                  v-model="selectedCountry"
                  :items="countryList"
                  item-text="country"
                  item-value="code"
                  return-object
                  single-line
                  v-on:change="countryChange"
                ></v-select>
              </v-col>
              <v-col align-self="center">
                <v-text-field
                  class="text-blue"
                  length="10"
                  filled
                  rounded
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>
        </v-content>
      </v-app>
    </div>

    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        data() {
          return {
            selectedCountry: { country: "United States (+1)", code: "+1" },
            countryList: [
              { country: "United States (+1)", code: "+1" },
              { country: "Canada (+1)", code: "+1c" },
              { country: "Australia (+61)", code: "+61" },
              { country: "Austria (+43)", code: "+43" },
              { country: "Belgium (+32)", code: "+32" },
              { country: "Bulgaria (+359)", code: "+359" },
              { country: "Croatia (+385)", code: "+385" },
              { country: "Cyprus (+357)", code: "+357" },
              { country: "Czech Republic (+420)", code: "+420" },
              { country: "Denmark (+45)", code: "+45" },
              { country: "Estonia (+372)", code: "+372" },
              { country: "Finland (+358)", code: "+358" },
              { country: "France (+33)", code: "+33" },
              { country: "Germany (+49)", code: "+49" },
              { country: "Greece (+30)", code: "+30" },
              { country: "Hungary (+36)", code: "+36" },
              { country: "Ireland (+353)", code: "+353" },
              { country: "Italy (+39)", code: "+39" },
              { country: "Latvia (+371)", code: "+371" },
              { country: "Lithuania (+370)", code: "+370" },
              { country: "Luxembourg (+352)", code: "+352" },
              { country: "Malta (+356)", code: "+356" },
              { country: "Mexico (+52)", code: "+52" },
              { country: "Netherlands (+31)", code: "+31" },
              { country: "New Zealand (+64)", code: "+64" },
              { country: "Poland (+48)", code: "+48" },
              { country: "Portugal (+351)", code: "+351" },
              { country: "Romania (+40)", code: "+40" },
              { country: "Singapore (+65)", code: "+65" },
              { country: "Slovakia (+421)", code: "+421" },
              { country: "Slovenia (+386)", code: "+386" },
              { country: "South Africa (+27)", code: "+27" },
              { country: "Spain (+34)", code: "+34" },
              { country: "Sweden (+46)", code: "+46" },
              { country: "United Kingdom (+44)", code: "+44" },
              { country: "Other (+0)", code: "+0" }
            ],
          };
        },
        methods: {
          countryChange(o) {
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this.$el.outerText);
            console.log(o.code);
            console.log(o.country);
            console.log(o);
          },
        },
        computed: {},
        beforeMount() {},
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Update]: To provide an example, I'm taking this [Maz-ui component](https://louismazel.github.io/maz-ui/documentation/maz-phone-number-input) that when clicked shows the complete country information in dropdown BUT shows only country code +1 in the field once selected. This basically is because the item-text is changed to +1 instead of United States on selection completion. How do I achieve this? I tried using onchange function to change the item-text to 'selectedCountry.code' instead of country - didn't seem to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using vuetify v-select component. It takes array of strings or array of objects like what you are using in code above.

`item-text` prop takes the property to display.
`item-value` takes property to return as a value when the option is selected.
You are using `return-object` as well which will return the whole object instead of the  `item-value`

Finally to show +43 instead of Austria (+43) you have to change `item-text` to code instead of country
Like this `item-text="code"`

Comment: Thanks for this islam - changing item-text seems to be the problem. Now, I don't want item-text to always show code.. I want it to change to code only when selection is completed. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Remove return-object and make item-text show text on options. And item-value return code

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with one workaround, In the dropdown you can show the `code` and on select you can show the `country` as a hint by using `:hint` keyword and vice versa.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    countryList: [
              { country: "United States (+1)", code: "+1" },
              { country: "Canada (+1)", code: "+1c" },
              { country: "Australia (+61)", code: "+61" },
              { country: "Austria (+43)", code: "+43" },
              { country: "Belgium (+32)", code: "+32" },
              { country: "Bulgaria (+359)", code: "+359" },
              { country: "Croatia (+385)", code: "+385" },
              { country: "Cyprus (+357)", code: "+357" },
              { country: "Czech Republic (+420)", code: "+420" },
              { country: "Denmark (+45)", code: "+45" },
              { country: "Estonia (+372)", code: "+372" },
              { country: "Finland (+358)", code: "+358" },
              { country: "France (+33)", code: "+33" },
              { country: "Germany (+49)", code: "+49" },
              { country: "Greece (+30)", code: "+30" },
              { country: "Hungary (+36)", code: "+36" },
              { country: "Ireland (+353)", code: "+353" },
              { country: "Italy (+39)", code: "+39" },
              { country: "Latvia (+371)", code: "+371" },
              { country: "Lithuania (+370)", code: "+370" },
              { country: "Luxembourg (+352)", code: "+352" },
              { country: "Malta (+356)", code: "+356" },
              { country: "Mexico (+52)", code: "+52" },
              { country: "Netherlands (+31)", code: "+31" },
              { country: "New Zealand (+64)", code: "+64" },
              { country: "Poland (+48)", code: "+48" },
              { country: "Portugal (+351)", code: "+351" },
              { country: "Romania (+40)", code: "+40" },
              { country: "Singapore (+65)", code: "+65" },
              { country: "Slovakia (+421)", code: "+421" },
              { country: "Slovenia (+386)", code: "+386" },
              { country: "South Africa (+27)", code: "+27" },
              { country: "Spain (+34)", code: "+34" },
              { country: "Sweden (+46)", code: "+46" },
              { country: "United Kingdom (+44)", code: "+44" },
              { country: "Other (+0)", code: "+0" }
            ],
    selectedCountry: null
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.6/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
          <v-select
            :items="countryList"
            v-model="selectedCountry"
            label="Select Country Code"
            item-text="code"
            return-object
            :hint="selectedCountry?.country.split('(')[0].trim()"
            outlined
          ></v-select>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rohit - I've added an update that gives an example of my problem statement.